# Finding inconsistency in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say that at some point after several `SELECT`s and `JOIN`s, I have a following result:

```
  Col1   Col2
+------+------+
|  1   |   2  |
|  1   |   3  |
|  4   |   5  |
|  4   |   6  |
|  5   |   6  |
|  6   |   7  |
+------+------+
```

Now I want to find "inconsistencies", i.e. to display rows that have the same values in `Col1` but different values in `Col2`. If there is just one occurrence of a value in `Col1`, then I don't want to display it at all.

What I've tried:

```
select Col1, Col2
from Table1
    group by Col1
    having (count(*) > 1)
```

It returns

```
  Col1   Col2
+------+------+
|  1   |   2  |
|  4   |   5  |
+------+------+
```

Expected result:

```
  Col1   Col2
+------+------+
|  1   |   2  |
|  1   |   3  |
|  4   |   5  |
|  4   |   6  |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.* from  
 (select col1,count(*)
  from table1
  group by col1
  having count(*) > 1) t2
join table1 t1 on t1.c1 = t2.c1
```

You should use a outer query after you find the counts which are > 1.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/211a9e/6

Comment: Thank you, didn't think about join :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Col1 IN (
  SELECT Col1 FROM Table1 GROUP BY Col1 HAVING COUNT(Col1) > 1
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8de26/2

Answer (score 0):

You should use this one instead of those:

```
select Col1, Col2
from Table1
    sort by Col1
    having (count(*) > 1)
```